# Whats the equivalent of the unix tree command on OSX

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix

Whats the equivalent of the [unix tree](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm) command on OSX (10.8.5)

Answer (score 16):

You can install `tree` via [Homebrew](http://wiki.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/):

- Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation) for the basic installation
- Run `brew install tree` to install the tool